# arm_cfft_sR_q31_len4096 undeclared

Tags: c, arm, embedded, signal-processing, cmsis

I am doing some FFT calculations on a STM32F407 and I want to compare the different FFT functions that is available in the CMSIS DSP library. When I am using the f32 CFFT functions it works as one would expect but when I try to use the q31/q15 functions I get an error saying "arm_cfft_sR_q31_len4096" or arm_cfft_sR_q15_len4096 undeclared when I call their respective cfft functions. I have included arm_const_structs.h where it should be defined but apparently it isn't? It works with arm_cfft_sR_f32_len4096 for the f32 version of the functions so what might be the problem?

Here is how the f32 version of my fft calculations look:

```
#include "arm_const_structs.h"

float32_t fft_data[FFT_SIZE * 2];

uint16_t util_calculate_fft_value(uint16_t *buffer, uint32_t len, uint32_t fft_freq, uint32_t fft_freq2) 
{
  uint16_t i;
  float32_t maxValue;         // Max FFT value is stored here
  uint32_t maxIndex;          // Index in Output array where max value is

  tmStartMeasurement(&time);  // Record clock cycles

  // Ensure in buffer is not longer than FFT buffer
  if (len > FFT_SIZE)
    len = FFT_SIZE;

  // Convert buffer uint16 to fft input float32
  for (i = 0; i < len ; i++) 
  {
    fft_data[i*2] = (float32_t)buffer[i] / 2048.0 - 1.0; // Real part
    fft_data[i*2 + 1] = 0; // Imaginary part      
  }

  // Process the data through the CFFT module intFlag = 0, doBitReverse = 1
  arm_cfft_f32(&arm_cfft_sR_f32_len4096, fft_data, 0, 1);
  // Process the data through the Complex Magniture Module for calculating the magnitude at each bin
  arm_cmplx_mag_f32(fft_data, fft_data, FFT_SIZE / 2);
  // Find maxValue as max in fft_data
  arm_max_f32(fft_data, FFT_SIZE, &maxValue, &maxIndex);

  if (fft_freq == 0) 
  { // Find maxValue as max in fft data
    arm_max_f32(fft_data, FFT_SIZE, &maxValue, &maxIndex);
  } 
  else 
  { // Grab maxValue from fft data at freq position
    arm_max_f32(&fft_data[fft_freq * FFT_SIZE / ADC_SAMP_SPEED - 1], 3, &maxValue, &maxIndex);

    if (fft_freq2 != 0) 
    {
      // Grab maxValue from fft data at freq2 position
      float32_t maxValue2;                // Max FFT value is stored here
      uint32_t maxIndex2;                // Index in Output array where max value is
      arm_max_f32(&fft_data[fft_freq * FFT_SIZE / ADC_SAMP_SPEED - 1], 3, &maxValue2, &maxIndex2);
      maxValue = (maxValue + maxValue2) / 2.0;
    }
  }

  tmStopMeasurement(&time); // Get number of clock cycles

  // Convert output back to uint16 for plotting
  for (i = 0; i < len / 2; i++) 
  {
    buffer[i] = (uint16_t)(fft_data[i] * 10.0);
  }
  // Zero the rest of the buffer
  for (i = len / 2; i < len; i++) 
  {
    buffer[i] = 0;
  }

  LOG_INFO("FFT number of cycles: %i\n", time.worst);

  return ((uint16_t)(maxValue * 10.0));
}
```

Comment: Post the exact text of the error message that you're getting.

Comment: What have you done to resolve the problem yourself (except for asking others)? Did you even look into the headers?

Comment: The code you have posted uses `arm_cfft_sR_f32_len4096`.  You should post teh code that exhibits the problem you are asking about, not teh code that works!  How are we supposed to see a problem in code that has no problem?!

Answer (score 1):

I found a copy of arm_const_structs.h online.  It includes the following line:

```
extern const arm_cfft_instance_q31 arm_cfft_sR_q31_len4096;
```

The `extern` keyword means that this line is a *declaration* of `arm_cfft_SR_q31_len4096`, not a *definition*.  The variable must also be defined somewhere else in your code.

I found the definition in arm_const_structs.c.

```
const arm_cfft_instance_q31 arm_cfft_sR_q31_len4096 = {
    4096, twiddleCoef_4096_q31, armBitRevIndexTable_fixed_4096, ARMBITREVINDEXTABLE_FIXED_4096_TABLE_LENGTH
};
```

Make sure you have included arm_const_structs.c in your project so that it compiles and links with your program.

Comment: Okay, where did you find that? On the version that is on github https://github.com/ARM-software/CMSIS/blob/master/CMSIS/Include/arm_const_structs.h the f32 one is extern as well

Comment: I found it simply by Googling for the file name.  Yes, all the declarations are `extern` in the _.h_ file.  You need to link with the _.c_ file in order to get the definitions.

Comment: @kkrambo : You have missed the point I think - he says that it works for `arm_cfft_sR_f32_len4096` which is also `extern`, so he must already be linking the definition for that at least.  Moreover the error is "undeclared" not "undefined" - that suggests that the *declaration* is not visible.

Comment: @Clifford I understand what you're saying.  The copy of the .h file that I found contains the declaration and it's not enclosed within any #ifdefs.  So either he has a different version of the .h file, or he's not really including the .h file, or he misspelled the variable name, or he misreported the error message.  Given what's written in the question, this last possibility seemed most plausible to me so that's the answer I went with.

Comment: Agreed - and I note that your request for the verbatim error message has not yet been addressed.  Who knows why this essentially incomplete question has been up-voted?!